# Two groups of checkboxes, how to throw validation error if at least one checkbox is not checked in either group

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

Total jQuery n00b. I have the following (simplified) form with two categories/groups of checkboxes (leaving out all other inputs):

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    Category 1:
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" id="check2" value="2" />
    ...
    Category 2:
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" id="check3" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check4" id="check4" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I am trying to throw a client-side validation error if, after a submit, no checkbox is checked in Category 1 or if no checkbox is checked in Category 2.

Again, being a jQuery n00b, I've seen some examples that throw the error to a pop-up box. However, what I want is for an error to be thrown in the validation error `<div>` that is set up using jquery.unobtrusive.validation (can't remember the exact name). Also, that the names are all different prevents me from using some of the easier examples out there.

The checkboxes are actually booleans (cannot use a checkbox list in this instance) in my model, using ASP.net MVC. I would, therefore, actually have the code: `@Html.Checkbox(m => m.Model.Check1)` and so on in my `.cshtml` view. I don't believe that's relevant. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to give one class to the first group of checkboxes, say `category1`, and another to the second group, such as `category2`. Then you'd do something like

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
    if ($(".category1:checked").length == 0 || $(".category2:checked").length == 0) {
        $("#errormessage").append("<p>You must check at least one checkbox in each category!</p>"); // Or however you want the validation error to be displayed
        return false;
    }
});
```

But less repetitive would be to put a `div` or other container element around the checkboxes in each group, and then give each div its own class or ID (so you have one `.category1` div that contains all the checkboxes in category 1 and one `.category2` div containing all the checkboxes in category 2). Then you'd use $(".category1 :checked") and $(".category2 :checked") as the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
if ($('#check1,#check2').filter(':checked').length <= 0 || 
         $('#check3,#check4').filter(':checked').length <= 0) {
   // error message
}
```

You'll have to figure the rest out yourself, since you've posted no useful details about exactly HOW you're validating this form.

Comment: This only makes sure one of the checkboxes is checked, not that at least one in each category is, which appears to be the requirement here.